Using behaviors to bind the SelectedItems of the DataGrid in WPF doesn't work
My idea is to use behaviors to bind the SelectedItems of the DataGrid. I've created a behavior named DataGridSelectItemsBehavior. There is a dependency property called MySlectItemsProperty. I'm monitoring the changes of AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged. When a change is detected, I'll obtain the binding of the object and then update the binding on the front end.
public class DataGridSelectItemsBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MySlectItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MySlectItems", typeof(IList), typeof(DataGridSelectItemsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectIndex", typeof(int), typeof(DataGridSelectItemsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(-1));

    public IList MySlectItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(MySlectItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MySlectItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public int SelectIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
            MySlectItems = dataGrid.SelectedItems;
            SelectIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
            var s = dataGrid.GetBindingExpression(MySlectItemsProperty);
        }

    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
    }
}

In the AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged method, it is found that s is always NULL
Here comes the XAML next.
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1"
    xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=System"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding personInfos}">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <local:DataGridSelectItemsBehavior MySlectItems="{Binding UserSelectedItems1, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectIndex="{Binding Select, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Index}" Header="序号" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="年龄" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Salary}" Header="工资" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="电话" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="住址" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>

I've confirmed that there are UserSelectedItems1 and Select properties in the ViewModel, and there is no prompt indicating any binding failure in Visual Studio.
I can't find any method that can help me obtain the correct approach.

Do you need to be able to select UI rows from the view model? If you don't then you could maybe just bind is selected of the datagridrow to a property in your item view model. Just use linq in the bound item view models to find what's selected.

I suggest you use a more general approach.
Here is my implementation for setting a separate binding to any Dependency Property, including those "read-only".
Main topic in Russian: Behavior for Binding Read-Only Properties [WPF, Eld Hasp]
    public class BindingToReadOnlyPropertyBehavior : Behavior<DependencyObject>
    {
        public PropertyPath Property { get => binding.Path; set => binding.Path = value; }
 
        private readonly Binding binding = new Binding("") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay };
 
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            binding.Source = AssociatedObject;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, SourceProperty, binding);
        }
 
        /// <summary>Private property for getting data by given binding.</summary>
        private object Source
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }
 
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Source.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        private static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(object), typeof(BindingToReadOnlyPropertyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, propertyChangedCallback));
 
        /// <summary>Callback method to pass the received value to the target binding.</summary>
        /// <param name="d"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private static void propertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            => ((BindingToReadOnlyPropertyBehavior)d).Target = e.NewValue;
 
        /// <summary>The target object where the value should be passed.</summary>
        public object Target
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(TargetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TargetProperty, value); }
        }
 
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Target.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(object), typeof(BindingToReadOnlyPropertyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));
 
    }

Example oа use:
    public partial class VMClass : OnPropertyChangedClass
    {
        public double Width { get => _width; set { _width = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        private double _width;
    }

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VMClass/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:BindingToReadOnlyPropertyBehavior  Target="{Binding Width, Mode=TwoWay}" Property="ActualWidth" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Width}"/>
    </Grid>

For your code it will be like this:
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid1"
    xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=System"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding personInfos}">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:BindingToReadOnlyPropertyBehavior
            Target="{Binding UserSelectedItems1, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Property="DataGrid.SelectedItems" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

To bind correctly, the "UserSelectedItems" property of your ViewModel must be of type IList or more basic (ICollection, IЕnumerable).
